# guess number in different way python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My program is supposed to guess a number. First, the user guesses a number (in their head) and doesn't tell the computer. Then, the computer starts to guess the number. The user sees the number the computer guessed and sends one of three types of string:

- 'c' means correct and finish
- 'b' means bigger number
- 'l' means lower number.

I have a problem: when the system guesses the number it takes too long to find the answer because range of random doesn't change in the program. Can somebody help me improve the code to become more efficient?

```
import random
b = 0
a = 0
hads = random.randint(1,99)
print(hads)
user = str(input('bigger or lower number : '))
while user != 'c':
   if user == 'b':
       a = hads
       b = 99
   elif user == 'l':
       b = hads
       a = 1
   hadss = random.randint(a,b)
   print(hadss)
   user = str(input('bigger or lower number : '))
print('woooow')
```

Comment: its hard to read your text. I would suggest to add some paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should initiate the a and b at the very beginning, then in the loop you can just change the one variable. The problem you have is you constantly reset the `a` and `b` to their initial value `1` and `99`, so basically your code just randomly guesses between `1` and `99`, and this is why it takes so long!

```
import random
b = 99
a = 1

hads = random.randint(a,b)
print(hads)
user = str(input('behem begoo cheghadr fasele daram : '))

while user != 'c':
   if user == 'b':
       a = hads
   elif user == 'l':
       b = hads
   hads = random.randint(a,b)
   print(hads)
   user = str(input('behem begoo cheghadr fasele daram : '))
print('woooow')
```

Comment: I think your `if` statements are backwards. If I read the OP correctly, `'b'` means "too big" which means the upper bound `b` should be set to the guess.

Comment: no. 'b' mean that the number the user has in their mind is bigger than the guess

Answer (score 1):

If the number is too big, then you should change `b`, but leave `a` the same. Similarly, if the number is too low, then you should change `a` and leave `b` the same:

```
if user == 'b':
  a = hads
elif user == 'l':
  b = hads
```

This is very similar to a "binary search". I suggest you read about this fundamental algorithm.

You should also read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to learn some tricks to debug your code.

Comment: my problem is to make the range each time smaller and smaller to end the game faster.how can i do that?

Comment: @nimarezazadeh The change I suggest to your `if` statement will do exactly that. The problem with your original code is that you don't make the range smaller because you keep resetting `a` to `1` and `b` to `99`.

Comment: @nimarezazadeh I might have the `if` statements reversed from what they should be. When you say "bigger number", do you mean that the guess is too big? Or do you mean that the number the user has in their mind is bigger than the guess?

Comment: i mean that the number the user has in their mind is bigger than the guess

Comment: @nimarezazadeh Then the `a` and `b` need to be switched from my original answer. The new edited answer should be correct. If you still have trouble, use the tips in the article I linked at the end of my answer to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

You started with hads and then wrote hadss. You never use hadss after the assignment. Change that to hads and it should work.

Comment: If you initialize a with 1 and b with 99, you can move the line hads =random.randint(a,b)              to the inside of the while loop and remove the faulty line hadss=..  altogether.

Comment: i change it and doesnt work.my problem is to make the range each time smaller and smaller to end the game faster.

Comment: Use print to check a and b during the run. It should show you whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it this way.

```
import sys
import random
b = 99
a = 1
user=''
hads = random.randint(a,b)
while user != 'c':
    print hads
    print a, ' ',b
    user = input('bigger or lower number : ')
    print user
    if user == 'b':
        a = hads
    elif user == 'l':
        b = hads
    hads = random.randint(a, b)
print('woooow')
```